# Change data on the fly - Event GA

Tags: php, events, google-analytics

On my site wants to change data on the fly (Wordpress).

So that the name of the product was downloaded from the page code and was auto-injected into Even GA.

I created this code:

```
$out_name = $b;
preg_match('~<span class="Title">([^<]*)</span>~Usmi', $out_name, $name);
$name_product = $name[1];

$what[] = 'class="OfferLink">';
$on[] = 'itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" onclick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', \''.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'\', \''.$name_product.'\');" class="OfferLink">';
$b = str_replace($what,$on,$b);
```

The name of the product is taken and thrown into place, but everywhere is generated the same.

[image: Look this picture.]

Comment: Is that inside a loop ? else `$name_product` will never change

Comment: No. @Tushar Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: For that I need to look into your complete code and you need to explain in detail how you are pulling data and what are you doing exactly ;)

Comment: @Tushar my code: